# How the client is related to the other classes in my class diagram?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I'm combining two design pattern Observer and Composite, everything go well with the code. My question is about the class diagram. I put the picture of my class diagram here
[image: Es1ClassDiagConClient.jpg]

and here i put my main

```
public class Compito24Febbraio2017 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcreteObserver o = new ConcreteObserver();
        Composite c1 = new Composite ("c1",o);
        Leaf l1 = new Leaf("l1",o);
        Leaf l2 = new Leaf("l2",o);
        c1.add(l1);
        c1.add(l2);
        c1.setState(5);
        l1.setState(4);
        o.printAllState();
    }
}
```

So the question is very simple and maybe I put too many stuff in this question;
Is it good this association with Observer and Component? (beacause the client has a reference of this two classes).
Maybe I should use a dependency relation? (Because the client creates an istance of some subclass of this two classes). Or maybe I should link the client with the ConcreteObserver, the Composite and the Leaf class with an association?

Comment: I'd say that you don't need a bidirectional association between components and observers. You probably want the components to tell all registered observers (not just one) when they've updated and in that case they could pass a reference to themselves to `update()` and thus the observers don't have to know about the components they're observing. The client on the other hand might create the observers but might not have to keep them. Instead the observers could keep a reference to the client if they need to inform the client of changes (in that sense the client observes the observers).

Answer (score 1):

You just need an association to the `ConcreteObserver`, not the `<<abstract>>` one. The observer already has an association to `Component` so you don't need any dependency from the client side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A point, the link between Component and ConcreteObserver should maybe be in the other direction no ?
If I look at [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) I feel that the link is in the other direction.

Comment: Yes in the observer pattern it's like this but this is a push observer and this specific case the observer is global and observe multiple subject.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So let me know if I understand, this is a decorator pattern and this is the main

```
public class DecoratorPatternDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Shape circle = new Circle();

      Shape redCircle = new RedShapeDecorator(new Circle());

      Shape redRectangle = new RedShapeDecorator(new Rectangle());
      System.out.println("Circle with normal border");
      circle.draw();

      System.out.println("\nCircle of red border");
      redCircle.draw();

      System.out.println("\nRectangle of red border");
      redRectangle.draw();
   }
}
```

Here the client has an association only with ShapeDecorator because in the main, the client creates a new RedShapeDecorator object which is a subclass of ShapeDecorator. The client creates also a Shape object but the client doesn't need to be associated with Shape because the class ShapeDecorator has already a reference of Shape. Am I right?